# Why is e.Item.DataItem null on ItemDataBound event when binding an asp:net Repeater to a Collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to bind a collection implementing the ICollection, IEnumerable and IList interface to an asp.net repeater. The Collection is named CustomCollection. So I'm setting the datasource of the repeater to the collection, as follows:

```
rptRepeater.DataSource = customCollection;
rptRepeater.Databind();
```

Then, on the ItemDataBound event, I'm trying to access the DataItem object, as follow:

```
void rptRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e){

object obj = e.Item.DataItem; // DataItem is null for some reason

}
```

For some reason the e.Item.DataItem object is null. Do anyone know why this is, and/or what I could do to get hold of the object in the collection that is to be databound to the repeater?

Thanx!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your `ItemDataBound` event handler, you need to check that it is not trying to bind to a header or footer template:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
    object obj = e.Item.DataItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

also you could use :

`if(e.item.dataItem != null)
     object obj = e.Item.DataItem;`